# java.time.Instant.atZone(...) far in the past return crazy values

Tags: java

I detect the following output when converting an Instant that is far in the past to a ZonedDateTime.

Code as Unit-Test:

```
   @Test
public void testParseDate() {
    Instant instant = Instant.parse("0000-12-30T07:00:00Z");
    System.out.println(instant);
    System.out.println(instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")));

    instant = Instant.parse("1800-12-30T07:00:00Z");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------");
    System.out.println(instant);
    System.out.println(instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")));

    instant = Instant.parse("1900-12-30T07:00:00Z");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------");
    System.out.println(instant);
    System.out.println(instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")));
}
```

Output:

```
0000-12-30T07:00:00Z
0000-12-30T07:53:28+00:53:28[Europe/Berlin]
---------------------------------
1800-12-30T07:00:00Z
1800-12-30T07:53:28+00:53:28[Europe/Berlin]
---------------------------------
1900-12-30T07:00:00Z
1900-12-30T08:00+01:00[Europe/Berlin]
```

In the first two outputs the time is 07:53:28+00:53:28 and the last output is 08:00+01:00[Europe/Berlin]. Maybe the root cause is that the time zone stuff doesn't yet exists in the years of the first two examples, but the offset of +00:53:28 is really strange.
Any idea where this offset "+00:53:28" comes from?

Answer (score 8):

Because **history**.

On April 1st, 1893, the time zone was adjusted from Local Mean Time (LMT), a local time zone (which was common at that time), to Central European Time (CET), adjusting the clock by 6 minutes and 32 seconds.

Timezones are regularly changed due to political decisions, but those strange amounts like 6 minutes and 32 seconds are often the result of moving from a local mean time to a standardized time.

Many known historical changes are found at [timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com), and Berlin specifically at https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/germany/berlin.

Comment: You can actually see all of these bizarre transitions in Java by examining the properties of a [ZoneId’s rules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html#getRules()).

Answer (score 3):

Timezones, Daylight Saving, and all those annoying and fancy features, did not exist at the beginning of the 20th century.

There were many "variations" of the time, like the infamous [Dutch Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B00:20) which was about 19 minutes ahead of UTC, mostly based on the clock of a tower which was simply that amount of time ahead.

I don't know *exactly* where the time difference comes from in the case of Germany and Berlin, but it's a known offset (likely based on similar reasons as the Dutch Time).

You can see [how it has evolved](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/germany/berlin?syear=1850) over time.